I encountered the following problem when running the DeeplabV3 code in Tensorflow according to the official tutorial
Detailed error information is below：
enter image description here
This is my Tensorflow versionenter image description here
The source of the error code comes from：
model, eval_logs = tfm.core.train_lib.run_experiment(
    distribution_strategy=distribution_strategy,
    task=task,
    mode='train_and_eval',
    params=exp_config,
    model_dir=model_dir,
    eval_summary_manager=summary_manager_instance,
    run_post_eval=False
)

Below is my entire code:
import os
import pprint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython import display

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import orbit
import tensorflow_models as tfm
from official.vision.data import tfrecord_lib
import tensorflow.summary
from orbit.utils import summary_manager


from official.vision.serving import export_saved_model_lib
from official.vision.utils.object_detection import visualization_utils

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)  # Set Pretty Print Indentation
print(tf.__version__)  # Check the version of tensorflow used


(train_ds, val_ds, test_ds), info = tfds.load(
    'oxford_iiit_pet:3.*.*',
    split=['train+test[:50%]', 'test[50%:80%]', 'test[80%:100%]'],
    with_info=True)
info



def process_record(record):
    keys_to_features = {
        'image/encoded': tfrecord_lib.convert_to_feature(

            tf.io.encode_jpeg(record['image']).numpy()),
        'image/height': tfrecord_lib.convert_to_feature(record['image'].shape[0]),
        'image/width': tfrecord_lib.convert_to_feature(record['image'].shape[1]),
        'image/segmentation/class/encoded': tfrecord_lib.convert_to_feature(
            tf.io.encode_png(record['segmentation_mask'] - 1).numpy())
    }
    example = tf.train.Example(
        features=tf.train.Features(feature=keys_to_features))
    return example



output_dir = './oxford_iiit_pet_tfrecords/'  
LOG_EVERY = 100
if not os.path.exists(output_dir): 
    os.mkdir(output_dir) 


# @tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert
def write_tfrecords(dataset, output_path, num_shards=1):
     writers = [
        tf.io.TFRecordWriter(
            output_path + '-%05d-of-%05d.tfrecord' % (i, num_shards))  
        for i in range(num_shards)
    ]

    for idx, record in enumerate(dataset):  
        if idx % LOG_EVERY == 0:
            print('On image %d', idx)  
        tf_example = process_record(record)  
        writers[idx % num_shards].write(tf_example.SerializeToString())




output_train_tfrecs = output_dir + 'train'
write_tfrecords(train_ds, output_train_tfrecs, num_shards=10)



output_val_tfrecs = output_dir + 'val'
write_tfrecords(val_ds, output_val_tfrecs, num_shards=5)



output_test_tfrecs = output_dir + 'test'
write_tfrecords(test_ds, output_test_tfrecs, num_shards=5)

train_data_tfrecords = './oxford_iiit_pet_tfrecords/train*'
val_data_tfrecords = './oxford_iiit_pet_tfrecords/val*'
test_data_tfrecords = './oxford_iiit_pet_tfrecords/test*'


trained_model = './trained_model/'
export_dir = './exported_model/'



exp_config = tfm.core.exp_factory.get_exp_config('mnv2_deeplabv3_pascal')


print(exp_config)


model_ckpt_path = './model_ckpt/'
if not os.path.exists(model_ckpt_path):
    os.mkdir(model_ckpt_path)



num_classes = 3  
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 128, 128  
input_size = [HEIGHT, WIDTH, 3]  
BATCH_SIZE = 16  

# Backbone Config
exp_config.task.init_checkpoint = model_ckpt_path + 'best_ckpt-63'
exp_config.task.freeze_backbone = True

# Model Config
exp_config.task.model.num_classes = num_classes
exp_config.task.model.input_size = input_size

# Training Data Config
exp_config.task.train_data.aug_scale_min = 1.0
exp_config.task.train_data.aug_scale_max = 1.0
exp_config.task.train_data.input_path = train_data_tfrecords
exp_config.task.train_data.global_batch_size = BATCH_SIZE
exp_config.task.train_data.dtype = 'float32'
exp_config.task.train_data.output_size = [HEIGHT, WIDTH]
exp_config.task.train_data.preserve_aspect_ratio = False
exp_config.task.train_data.seed = 2  # Reproducable Training Data

# Validation Data Config
exp_config.task.validation_data.input_path = val_data_tfrecords
exp_config.task.validation_data.global_batch_size = BATCH_SIZE
exp_config.task.validation_data.dtype = 'float32'
exp_config.task.validation_data.output_size = [HEIGHT, WIDTH]
exp_config.task.validation_data.preserve_aspect_ratio = False
exp_config.task.validation_data.groundtruth_padded_size = [HEIGHT, WIDTH]
exp_config.task.validation_data.seed = 21  # Reproducable Validation Data
exp_config.task.validation_data.resize_eval_groundtruth = True  # To enable validation loss


logical_device_names = [logical_device.name
                        for logical_device in tf.config.list_logical_devices()]

if 'GPU' in ''.join(logical_device_names):
    print('This may be broken in Colab.')
    device = 'GPU'
elif 'TPU' in ''.join(logical_device_names):
    print('This may be broken in Colab.')
    device = 'TPU'
else:
    print('Running on CPU is slow, so only train for a few steps.')
    device = 'CPU'

train_steps = 2000
exp_config.trainer.steps_per_loop = int(train_ds.__len__().numpy() // BATCH_SIZE)

exp_config.trainer.summary_interval = exp_config.trainer.steps_per_loop
# steps_per_loop = num_of_validation_examples // eval_batch_size
exp_config.trainer.checkpoint_interval = exp_config.trainer.steps_per_loop
exp_config.trainer.validation_interval = exp_config.trainer.steps_per_loop
exp_config.trainer.validation_steps = int(
    train_ds.__len__().numpy() // BATCH_SIZE)  # validation_steps = num_of_validation_examples // eval_batch_size
exp_config.trainer.train_steps = train_steps
exp_config.trainer.optimizer_config.warmup.linear.warmup_steps = exp_config.trainer.steps_per_loop
exp_config.trainer.optimizer_config.learning_rate.type = 'cosine'
exp_config.trainer.optimizer_config.learning_rate.cosine.decay_steps = train_steps
exp_config.trainer.optimizer_config.learning_rate.cosine.initial_learning_rate = 0.1
exp_config.trainer.optimizer_config.warmup.linear.warmup_learning_rate = 0.05


pp.pprint(exp_config.as_dict())
display.Javascript('google.colab.output.setIframeHeight("500px");')



if exp_config.runtime.mixed_precision_dtype == tf.float16:
    tf.keras.mixed_precision.set_global_policy('mixed_float16')

if 'GPU' in ''.join(logical_device_names):
    distribution_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
elif 'TPU' in ''.join(logical_device_names):
    tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system()
    tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='/device:TPU_SYSTEM:0')
    distribution_strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(tpu)
else:
    print('Warning: this will be really slow.')
    distribution_strategy = tf.distribute.OneDeviceStrategy(logical_device_names[0])

print("Done")

model_dir = './trained_model/'

with distribution_strategy.scope():
    task = tfm.core.task_factory.get_task(exp_config.task, logging_dir=model_dir)

for images, masks in task.build_inputs(exp_config.task.train_data).take(1):
    print()
    print(f'images.shape: {str(images.shape):16}  images.dtype: {images.dtype!r}')
    print(f'masks.shape: {str(masks["masks"].shape):16} images.dtype: {masks["masks"].dtype!r}')



def plot_masks(display_list):
    plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))

    title = ['Input Image', 'True Mask', 'Predicted Mask']

    for i in range(len(display_list)):
        plt.subplot(1, len(display_list), i + 1)
        plt.title(title[i])
        plt.imshow(tf.keras.utils.array_to_img(display_list[i]))

        plt.axis('off')
    plt.switch_backend('TkAgg')
    plt.show()


num_examples = 3

for images, masks in task.build_inputs(exp_config.task.train_data).take(num_examples):
    plot_masks([images[0], masks['masks'][0]])




summary_dir = './trained_model/summary/'



def summary_function(name, value, step):
    with tf.summary.create_file_writer(summary_dir).as_default():
        tf.summary.scalar(name, value, step=step)


global_step_var = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
summary_manager_instance = summary_manager.SummaryManager(summary_dir=summary_dir,
                                                          summary_fn=summary_function,

print("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Problem！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！！")
exp_config = exp_config
model, eval_logs = tfm.core.train_lib.run_experiment(
    distribution_strategy=distribution_strategy,
    task=task,
    mode='train_and_eval',
    params=exp_config,
    model_dir=model_dir,
    eval_summary_manager=summary_manager_instance,
    run_post_eval=False
)

export_saved_model_lib.export_inference_graph(
    input_type='image_tensor',
    batch_size=1,
    input_image_size=[HEIGHT, WIDTH],
    params=exp_config,
    checkpoint_path=tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_dir),
    export_dir=export_dir)


imported = tf.saved_model.load(export_dir)
model_fn = imported.signatures['serving_default']




def create_mask(pred_mask):
    pred_mask = tf.math.argmax(pred_mask, axis=-1)
    pred_mask = pred_mask[..., tf.newaxis]
    return pred_mask[0]


for record in test_ds.take(15):
    image = tf.image.resize(record['image'], size=[HEIGHT, WIDTH])
    image = tf.cast(image, dtype=tf.uint8)
    mask = tf.image.resize(record['segmentation_mask'], size=[HEIGHT, WIDTH])
    predicted_mask = model_fn(tf.expand_dims(record['image'], axis=0))
    plot_masks([image, mask, create_mask(predicted_mask['logits'])])


I tried to search online, but did not find the same type of error like mine. Then I asked GPT, and his answer was as follows: This error message seems to be about the inability to represent Python objects through universal tracking types. This is usually because TensorFlow's tracing mechanism cannot handle certain Python objects, either because these objects are not of a type that TensorFlow can trace, or they need to implement the Tracing Protocol to be traced correctly.But the config here is imported from Tensorflow official: exp_config = tfm.core.exp_factory.get_exp_config('mnv2_deeplabv3_pascal')
. I don't know how to modify this congfig to be tracked correctly.My sincere thanks to every developer who helped me solve the problem!

The detailed error report is as follows: f"Python object could not be represented through the generic tracing "
TypeError: Python object could not be represented through the generic tracing type. Consider implementing the Tracing Protocol for it: ExperimentConfig（.....）

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\tFsnack\deeplab.py", line 288, in 
run_post_eval=False
File "F:\project1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py", line 154, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
